# Emacs: how hooks work?

Tags: function, emacs, elisp, hook

I had gone through a different tutorials and manuals, but still can't put a things together.

As I understand, when I need to add a new function to an event while an old functional still saved, I am add a hook by calling `add-hook`. From the manual entry on the `add-hook`:

> FUNCTION is added (if necessary) at the beginning of the hook list
>   unless the optional argument APPEND is non-nil

So the hook is just a *list* of a functions. But how is this list looks like? Works? From my little research I found that every *cons cell* besides the *car* and *cdr* have also an invisible unmentioned slot for a function pointer(may be an index, it doesn't matter). So how can I create manually a list of a functions, and execute it? Probably with `add-to-list` function, but everything I tried just triggers an errors. Also in the manual [mentioned](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html):

> You can set a hook variable with setq like any other Lisp variable,

Something is wrong here, because a pointer to a function don't get copied with setq. I.e.:

```
(defun myfunc1 () (message "hello"))
(setq onemorefunc 'myfunc1)
```

After I execute the `(onemorefunc)`, debugger triggers, the `setq` just ignores a value of the unnamed element in which the pointer stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a function that's in a variable, you have to use `funcall` or `apply`:

```
(funcall onemorefunc)

(apply onemorefunc '())
```

When Emacs is processing a hook variable, it iterates through the list:

```
(do ((hooks blah-hook (cdr hooks)))
    ((null hooks))
  (funcall (car hooks)))
```

Comment: Also, for more information, take a look at the manual about [running hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Running-Hooks.html)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, your `setq` merely makes `onemorefunc` another name for `myfunc1`. A hook needs to be a list, and you need to add your hook function to that list using `add-hook`, which is a glorified version of `push`, not replace the list completely with your function using `setq`. The mention of `setq` has misled you, though it's clear to someone who's familiar with hooks that it is telling you something *else* correctly. It says you can set a hook *variable* -- not a hook itself -- using `setq`, and you can, but what it doesn't make clear is that what you have to set that hook variable to is another list (of zero or more functions) not a function. Thus, assuming `my-mode-start-hook` is empty to begin:

```
(add-hook 'my-mode-start-hook #'my-func)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(setq my-mode-start-hook (list #'my-func))
```

In practice, you should always do the former, never the latter unless and until you're really sure you know what you're doing.